# How to get minute when I substrate between 2 hours in android?

Tags: java, android, time, hour, minute

I have 2 hours in day, and when i subtracting time I just only get hour value,
hour and minute is long data type.
How can get hour and minute?

example:
10:10 today - 7:45 tomorrow = 21 hour and 35 minute

Comment: Please post your code of what you have tried and how it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SimpleDateFormat class to give a complete date info:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date startDate = df.parse("2016-05-24 17:50:10");
        Date endDate = df.parse("2016-05-25 19:05:15");
        long diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

        int timeInSeconds = (int) (diff / 1000);
        int hours, minutes, seconds;
        hours = timeInSeconds / 3600;
        timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds - (hours * 3600);
        minutes = timeInSeconds / 60;
        timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds - (minutes * 60);
        seconds = timeInSeconds;

        System.out.println(String.format("%d:%d':%d\"", hours, minutes, seconds));
```